# How to create Chart with source from a different Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, charts

Before coming to ask I searched the web a lot, and the answers I found did not solve the problem.
The "Data" Worksheet is in the same Workbook as the "Reports" Worksheet.

[image]

This is the part of my code that matters for this question:

`Private Function CreateChart(ByVal DataRow As Integer, ByVal DataCol As Integer)
    Dim ChartRowOffset As Integer
    Charts.Add
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlPie
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Data").Range(Cells(2, DataCol), Cells(DataRow - 1, DataCol + 1)), PlotBy:=xlColumns
    ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Report"
    ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(1, DataCol).Value
    If DataCol > 1 Then
        ChartRowOffset = (DataCol - 1) * 2
    Else
        ChartRowOffset = 2
    End If
    With ActiveChart.Parent
        .Top = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Cells(ChartRowOffset, 1).Top
        .Left = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report").Cells(ChartRowOffset, 1).Left
    End With
End Function`

I am getting error code 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error" when I try to select a source from a different worksheet in this line:

`ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Data").Range(Cells(2, DataCol), Cells(DataRow - 1, DataCol + 1)), PlotBy:=xlColumns`

If I do it without Sheets("Data"), it gives no error and creates the chart, but it selects cells from the "Reports" sheet, not the Worksheet I need.
I tried selecting the "Data" Worksheet, activating it, nothing worked so far.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Rafael, I don't think you can use `Cells` to define a `Range` as you're mixing _A1_ and _R1C1_ [ReferenceStyles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ff835250(v%3doffice.14)). You can, however, continue with your method with this change - `ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("Data").Range(Cells(2, DataCol).Address, Cells(DataRow - 1, DataCol + 1).Address), PlotBy:=xlColumns`

Comment: Hello @JVBA , it worked! Thank you very much! Please add an answer so I can reward it.

Comment: Glad to hear, and will do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following to fix the referencing style issue -

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:= _
Sheets("Data").Range(Cells(2, DataCol).Address, Cells(DataRow - 1, DataCol + _
1).Address), PlotBy:=xlColumns
```

The infamous *Error: 1004* will haunt you to the death over stuff like this. Also, if I may, your code would be faster, shorter, and easier to read if you used *With* statements wherever applicable.

Ex:

```
With ActiveChart
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Report"
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Select
    .ChartTitle.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(1, DataCol).Value
End WIth
```

**-******UPDATE*******-**

After testing, I found I had to re-Set the variable... Seemed crazy to me, however, tested and worked for me:

```
Private Function CreateChart()

Dim cht As Chart
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
Set cht = Charts.Add

With cht
    .SetSourceData Source:=rng, PlotBy:=xlColumns
    .ChartType = xlPie
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Sheet1"
End With

Set cht = ActiveChart

With cht
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name
End With

End Function
```

Danny,

[ExcelVBADude](http://youtube.com/channel/UC5Z93LJulIuAICkZMSmcbGA/)

Comment: When I use With like you suggested I get this error: "The specified dimension is not valid for the current chart type" on the ".HasTitle = True" line.

Comment: Fixed above... for me at least. Let us know if something else pops up. I got Office 365 & VBA v7.1